# CodeIgniter & Smarty - can't change template dir - bridging smarty class doesn't overwrite setTemplateDir()

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, smarty

I am trying to add Smarty to CodeIgniter, here are the steps that I did:

1. Downloaded CI
2. Downloaded Smarty and put its content in 'application/third_party/smarty' folder
3. Created 'smarty.php' file in 'application/libraries'
4. Created 'templates' & 'templates_c' folders inside 'application/views' folder
5. Created simple 'test.tpl' file in 'application/views/templates' folder
6. Opened 'autoload.php' in 'application/config' folder and added:

   $autoload['libraries'] = array('smarty');
7. Inside a controller wrote `$this->smarty->display('test.tpl';`

And I get this error - `Message: Unable to load template file 'test.tpl'`

After some debugging I have noticed that my Smarty template dir is set to default, and not the one that is specified in the bridging class ('application/libraries/smarty.php')

Here is the bridging class content:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

class CI_Smarty extends Smarty {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // NOT Changig this for some reason
        $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH.'views/templates/');   
        $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH.'views/templates_c/');
    }

}
```

I think the CI_Smarty class isn't being executed for some reason, thats why my template directory is set to default

also note that if I go directly into Smarty.class.php and change the template directory manually - everything will work

Figured out the problem - bridging class should have been in 'system/libraries' and not in 'application/libraries' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to load `ci_smarty` library which extends `smarty`, not `smarty` directly.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('ci_smarty');
```

In your controller,

```
$this->ci_smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

**Important**

> Please note that all native CodeIgniter libraries are prefixed with
>   CI_ so DO NOT use that as your prefix.

Try to change library name to `custom_smarty` instead.

Last but not least

**Don't touch the system directory for any reason, Never ever. It is not the best practice. You can easily create new one or extend the existing libraries in your `application/libraries` directory.**

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Futher, if you like or need to use as

$this->smarty->display('test.tpl');

**First, please CLONE the 'ci_smarty' object into 'smarty' on the Controller __Consructor() function**
$this->smarty = clone $this->ci_smarty;